# webpack and multiple asset-manifest.json files

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am quite new in this javascript world, so maybe there is some error in my thinking.
I have in one react project more applications, which are build at once.
Because of caching issues I would like introduce hashing for javascript files.
And therefore I need multiple asset-manifest.json files.
I was thinking the webpack-assets-manifest plugin could do the job.
But, after playing with it for a while, I didn't find way how to generate correctly multiple asset-manifest.json files.
I cannot find some examples for it.

1. Is  webpack-assets-manifest plugin correct plugin do that job ?
2. What are other possibilities to fix such issue ?

(I am using webpack 5.x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So nobody wants to answer my question, so I have to do it :)
I solved this issue with  webpack-assets-manifest plugin.
The structure of desired manifest.json file is

```
{
  "files": {
    "private.js": "private/private-aab89d6bb658b9b19760.js",
    "private/index.html": "private/index.html",
  },
  "entrypoints": [
    "private/private-aab89d6bb658b9b19760.js"
  ]
}
```

Here is the method (config-overrides.js), which could do that:

```
function addManifestJsonFile(config, outputJsonFile, customerType) {
  const manifest = new WebpackAssetsManifest({
    output: outputJsonFile,
    customize: ({ key, value }) => {
      if (key.toLowerCase().endsWith('.txt')) return false;
      if (!key.toLowerCase().includes(customerType)) return false;
      return { key, value };
    },
    transform(assets) {
      return {
        files: assets,
        entrypoints: [assets[customerType + '.js']]
      };
    }
  });
  config.plugins.push(manifest);
}
```